# How do I bind this event handler in a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am learning JavaScript and jQuery, so I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question.

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.addDiv = function () {
    this.append('<div></div>');
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));

$('div').click(function () {
  $('body').addDiv();
});
```

In the code above, I have written a simple jQuery plugin which appends a `<div>` element to the current value of `this`.

Now, after I click on an element and add some `<div>` elements, I realize that the click handler in not associated with the newly appended elements. This seems perfectly acceptable since naturally when the handler function was bound, it was to only the ones that existed and hence were present in the `$('div')` object.

Now, I know that binding the handler to all `<div>` elements within the plugin is as simple as follows.

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.addDiv = function () {
    this.append('<div></div>');
    $('div').click(function () {
      $('body').addDiv();
    }); // added this statement
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));
```

But I'm sure that there is a better way to handle such event binding. This clearly duplicates code. **So what is the best practice with regards to such event binding to elements that the plugin itself adds?**

*This is meant to be an educational example, please do not consider it to be any kind of use case and give me alternative solutions.*

http://jsbin.com/jokururiyaca/1/edit

**Edit:** I know that some people recommend the use of `.selector` but it is deprecated in jQuery 2. Also, using it doesn't change the fact that the event handling code is still duplicated within the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way you could solve your problem of re-binding the click handler to all elements.

You can create the DOM element using `$('<div></div>')`, add the click handler to only that element, using `$('<div></div>').click(...)`, and then append it to the body with `$('<div></div>').click(...).appendTo("body")`.

**Example:**

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.addDiv = function () {
    $('<div></div>').click(function () {
      $('body').addDiv();
    }).appendTo("body");
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Usually [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) would be used to handle events on future elements.

**Example:**

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.addDiv = function () {
    this.append('<div></div>');
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));

$(document).on("click", "div", function(){
  $('body').addDiv();
});
```